# Transform data from a jsonb column into a table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, jsonb-array-elements

I have a table which stores timestamps but they're in a jsonb array column like this:

| id | cycles |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | [{"end": "2022-10-18T18:31:34.529667Z", "start": "2022-10-05T19:01:51.400124Z"}, {"start": "2022-10-28T08:27:13.682084Z"}] |
| 6 | [{"start": "2022-10-03T16:37:38.119236Z"}] |
| 7 | [{"end": "2022-11-14T11:30:17.964960Z", "start": "2022-11-08T19:20:20.413133Z"}] |

I need to the values from the start and end... and have a row per key in the json as the following:

| id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2022-10-05T19:01:51.400124Z | 2022-10-18T18:31:34.529667Z |
| 5 | 2022-10-28T08:27:13.682084Z |  |
| 6 | 2022-10-03T16:37:38.119236Z |  |
| 7 | 2022-11-08T19:20:20.413133Z | 2022-11-14T11:30:17.964960Z |

I've been trying with the following queries:

```
select  
    ks.id,  
    jsonb_path_query(KS.cycles, '$.start') AS start,    
    jsonb_path_query_array(KS.cycles, '$[*].start') as start  
from    
    table ks
```

But when I tried to run this I'm facing the following error: *ERROR: function jsonb_path_query_array(jsonb, unknown) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 84*

I've been searching but haven't been able to find something related to this... and by doing the simple:

```
select 
    ks.id,
    ks.cycles::jsonb ->> start
from 
    table ks
```

It doesn't work

I need help to build or change the query I'm working on.

Comment: What version of Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_to_recordset()`

```
select ks.id, 
       r.start, 
       r.end
from ks
  cross join jsonb_to_recordset(ks.cycles) as r("end" timestamptz, "start" timestamptz)      
order by ks.id, r.start
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me with changing `jsonb_path_query_array` to `jsonb_path_query` for the `end` values:

```
create table ks (id integer, cycles jsonb);

insert into ks values (5, '[{"end": "2022-10-18T18:31:34.529667Z", "start": "2022-10-05T19:01:51.400124Z"}, {"start": "2022-10-28T08:27:13.682084Z"}]'), (6, '[{"start": "2022-10-03T16:37:38.119236Z"}]'), (7, '[{"end": "2022-11-14T11:30:17.964960Z", "start": "2022-11-08T19:20:20.413133Z"}]');

select  
    ks.id,  
    jsonb_path_query(KS.cycles, '$.start') AS start,    
    jsonb_path_query(KS.cycles, '$.end') as end  
from    
    ks  ;
 id |             start             |              end              
----+-------------------------------+-------------------------------
  5 | "2022-10-05T19:01:51.400124Z" | "2022-10-18T18:31:34.529667Z"
  5 | "2022-10-28T08:27:13.682084Z" | NULL
  6 | "2022-10-03T16:37:38.119236Z" | NULL
  7 | "2022-11-08T19:20:20.413133Z" | "2022-11-14T11:30:17.964960Z"
```

Also your original query works:

```
select  
    ks.id,  
    jsonb_path_query(KS.cycles, '$.start') AS start,    
    jsonb_path_query_array(KS.cycles, '$[*].start') as end  
from    
    ks  ;
 id |             start             |                              end                               
----+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
  5 | "2022-10-05T19:01:51.400124Z" | ["2022-10-05T19:01:51.400124Z", "2022-10-28T08:27:13.682084Z"]
  5 | "2022-10-28T08:27:13.682084Z" | ["2022-10-05T19:01:51.400124Z", "2022-10-28T08:27:13.682084Z"]
  6 | "2022-10-03T16:37:38.119236Z" | ["2022-10-03T16:37:38.119236Z"]
  7 | "2022-11-08T19:20:20.413133Z" | ["2022-11-08T19:20:20.413133Z"]
```